# How much XP does it take per Paragon level?

Tags: diablo-iii

As of patch 2.0.1 paragon levels are no longer capped.  How can I figure out how much xp it takes per level of paragon?

---

Pre 2.0.1 patch:

Blizzard announced that there would be 100 additional "Paragon" levels after a player reached level 60. I'm not sure if they announced exactly how the increase in XP would work, but I was wondering if anyone knew the total amount of XP needed to get from Paragon level 0 to 100? A formula would also be helpful.

(The only detail I was able to uncover from Blizzard was that the first paragon level would be roughly the amount of xp it took to get from level 59 to 60)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

## *Lots*(!)

[Molster](http://www.diablofans.com/members/47963-molster) over at Diablofans [made a spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ArjwAbscCpNWdHdwXy10VldIWHUwR1hPU3NZa3BzRXc&usp=sharing) which details the amount of experience required to get Paragon levels with the new Paragon 2.0 system:

[image]

It is worth noting that these levels are *in addition* the 60 (70 in Reaper of Souls) character levels.

Comment: note that its roughly 1.5m more experience per paragon level up to around 60, then it starts scaling up drastically

Comment: Does blizzard actually     intent anyone to reach lvl 100?

Comment: People who want to reach 100 quickly will do - people who don't care so much will get there eventually. It's like the level cap in Diablo 2 being 99 but you never *really* needing above 85 or so - it's there so you have something to keep aiming for, which keeps people playing.

Comment: pretty much.  The last 20 levels is definitely not worth the effort compared to the gain since all you get is 60% mf (and a few stat points), which you can easily do with gear without a huge drop off in killing efficiency.

Comment: its crazy that there's a guy who's currently paragon 99, probably hitting paragon 100 as I type this

Comment: yeah - and this guy probably hasn't left his PC for more than 6 hours at any point in the last few weeks

Comment: @kalina you did need level 89 in Diablo 2 for some crafted amulets :)

Comment: there's a bounty if you update your answer *hint hint*

Comment: its worth noting it takes less xp to hit paragon 100 now than before.  And you'll have to wait 23 more hours before I can award the bounty :P

Comment: that xp sheet seems to be wrong, it says level 254 paragon is 370m xp but right now I need 438m

Answer (score 30):

There is also [this chart](http://www.diablofans.com/news/1320-paragon-level-exp-chart/), which shows the experience needed for each level.

[image]

So, you need 10,454,400,000 experience total, from level 60.

From the calculations in [this thread](http://www.reddit.com/r/Diablo/comments/yj87t/paragon_level_exp_chart/c5w38fc), starting from level 60, with full 75% NV buff, to get 100 paragon will require killing approximately 1,327,000 lvl 63 monsters, or 6,534,000 Inferno Hulking Phase Beasts, or 8,167,500 Inferno Dust Imps.

Happy hunting!

Comment: I think I will start singing "8,167,500 Inferno Dust Imps on the floor..." when I go on road trips with my family.  They will beg me to sing "100 beers on the wall..." instead.

Comment: Isn't the Geneva convention against this kind of behaviour ?

Comment: Thanks for the great answer and link. I found this very helpful as well

Comment: @blueraja +1 for good sources

Answer (score 1):

As of patch 2.0.1, there are no longer a cap to paragon levels. The amount of EXP required to advance to the next paragon level, before level 1488, is calculated by the following formula:

**`EXP required = Level * 1,440,000 + 5,760,000`**

For example, to get to level 18, you will need `18 * 1440000 + 5760000 = 31680000` EXP (from level 17).

However, once you hit paragon level 1488, it would require more than 2,147,483,647 EXP to advance  to the next level according to this linear increment. Since 2,147,483,647 is actually the maximum value of an `integer` typed variable in computer programming, the EXP requirement will stop its increment after level 1488. That is: You will need 2,147,483,647 EXP to advance one level after level 1488.

Comment: do you mind posting also what you receive at each level up?

Comment: @kalina You are right, my source was outdated since Blizzard changed the EXP requirement recently. I've updated my answer now. Thanks.

Comment: @ColinD According to mined data from Diablo Fans, it is in fact capped at 2,147,483,647 after Level 1488.

Comment: @user1032613 you're right according to diablo fans. I was misreading your last paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

We still have to find some sort of official formula. Charts and tables out there seem to rely on people playing the game and then interpolating the points. Even the diablofan article seem not to give a formula. However the formula provided as

```
EXP required = Level * 1,440,000 + 5,760,000
```

Seems to work. As for the level 1488 cap, this is NOT a limit for 64bits integers and since the cumulative experience goes far beyond the 32bit limit I guess there is no such cap.

Anyway we would need somebody at Blizzard to confirm or infirm our assumptions.